# What is this kind of graph called? (2D grid with a color-coded scale for a 3rd variable)

Tags: data-visualization

I keep running into these nice pictures:

[image]

But I have no idea what they are called!

Comment: Why did you use the survey tag? You probably want [tag:data-visualization], but if there is reason for the survey tag as well, please elaborate.

Comment: @NickStauner, it is essentially an exact duplicate, but in this case, the OP could hardly have been expected to have found that one. Questions like this will inevitably become one-offs.

Comment: @gung: I was tempted to edit the title just now so that it would be easier to find with a search, but at the same time, I notice a lot of really vague titles among the "Hot Network Questions", and wouldn't want to rob this one of its 15 minutes in the spotlight! (Especially because I was first to the mark on this one, TBH :)

Comment: @NickStauner, editing titles to make the nature of the question / thread clearer & easier to find is probably the most valuable edit possible (followed by tag edits in my hierarchy). I don't think this Q is headed for the HNQs w/ 35 views so far, so go ahead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming `C` and `gamma` are distinct from the third variable that is color-coded according to its (probably [binned](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_binning)) value for each combination of `C` and `gamma`, this is a [heat map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_map). Compare to this:

[image]
<sub>(source: [wikimedia.org](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/0f/Excel_Heat_Map.png))</sub>   Author: [George Halt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:George_Halt)